# How to present Array Of addresses data from Web Api On GoogleMapView iOS Swift4

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift4, geocoding, cllocation

I am try to get an array of addresses that are coming from webApi and load them on the googleMapView. First I have to convert the address into coordinates and then I am doing that. So I don't know where I am doing.. I am fetching data and I am using model classes... I might be doing this very wrong...

I am beginner as an iOS developer...
Somebody please guide me through this...

Code Here:

```
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import Alamofire

class HomeViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,GMSMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

   var JSONData = [LocationData]()
   var serviceNames = [ServiceName]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

       self.getProfessionalLocations()
}

 func getProfessionalLocations() {

        let url = "http://domailname.com/api/UsersAPI/GetLocationUsers"

        let parameters: NSDictionary = ["Address":""]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters as? [String:Any], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)

                self.proResponseArray = response.result.value as! NSArray

                for eachValue in self.proResponseArray {

                    let dataValue = eachValue as! [String : Any]
                    let professionalName = dataValue["userName"] as! String
                    let imagePath = "http://domailname.com/app/Users/ProfilePics/\(dataValue["profilePic"]!))"
                    let escapedAddress = imagePath.addingPercentEncoding(
                        withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
//                    self.infoWindow.profile_Img.image = UIImage(url: URL(string: escapedAddress!))

// here I am getting the address from the api
                    let address = dataValue["searchAddress"] as! String

                    let services = dataValue["lstServiceProviders"] as! NSArray

                    for allServiceNames in services {

                        let names = allServiceNames as! [String : Any]
                        let serviceName = names["serviceName"] as! String

                        self.serviceNames.append(ServiceName(serviceName: serviceName))
                    }

                    let experience = dataValue["experience"] as! String

                    let rating = dataValue["rating"] as Any

                    self.JSONData.append(LocationData(serviceNames: self.serviceNames, proName: professionalName, proImage:  escapedAddress!, address: address, experience: experience, rating: rating))
                }

                for location in self.JSONData {

                    let marker = GMSMarker()
                    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
                    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(location.address ) { (placemarks, error) in
                        guard
                            let placemarks = placemarks,
                            let addressLocation = placemarks.first?.location
                            else {
                                // handle no location found
                                return
                        }

                        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(addressLocation.coordinate.latitude, addressLocation.coordinate.longitude)
                        marker.icon = UIImage(named:"beautycare")!
                        self.googleMapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:addressLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: addressLocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: self.currentZoom)
                        marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
                        marker.map = self.googleMapView
                    }
                }

                break
            case .failure(let error):

                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
class ServiceName {

    var serviceName : String

    init(serviceName : String) {

        self.serviceName = serviceName
    }
}

class LocationData {

    var serviceNames : [ServiceName]
    var proName : String
    var proImage : String
    var address : String
    var experience : String
    var rating: Any

    init(serviceNames:[ServiceName], proName: String, proImage: String, address : String, experience: String, rating: Any) {

        self.serviceNames = serviceNames
        self.proName = proName
        self.proImage = proImage
        self.address = address
        self.experience = experience
        self.rating = rating
    }
}
```

Comment: well I would love to help, but I attempted to install the google maps sdk on IOS and it was overly complex... and extremely irritating.

Comment: You need to create completion handler method for getting Address from the lat/long. It will be fire once you will get all location from the lat/long. I wish It helps you.

Comment: @Shahabuddin Vansiwala Thanks for the reply and sorry for the late reply.. can you give some example code on how to do that coz I'm a beginner and I don't have much idea on how to use completion handlers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my below code you need to get all address from all lat/long. fire Completion handler Once all Address collected.

**Create Get Address List Function**

```
typealias CompletionHandlerButton = (_ response:NSMutableArray) -> Void
func AllLocationDetected(lotLongArray: NSMutableArray,handler: @escaping CompletionHandlerButton)
{
    //Write your logic here to Get address from the Lat/long and also need to check all address list collected or not.
    handler(ListOfAddress) //Send back your List of address here
}
```

**Fire Get All Adress List Function**

```
AllLocationDetected { (LocationArray) in

    print(LocationArray)

}
```

Hope It will help you!